# Problems implementing A star search C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star

I am trying to implement an A star algorithm with C++ in a game that I am creating and it is not working, I don't really know if there's something I've missed about the code or the algorithm. I've used sets because they are sorted and the return value is a vector with the nodes I've got to visit. I've never used this algorithm before so probably I've got some kind of error.

```
struct node {
    Pos pos;
    int f; //the sum of the distance from the goal to succcessor
    int g; // the sum of the cost of the current plus the one from the successor
    int h; //distance from goal to successor

friend bool operator< (node right, node left)  {
      return (right.f < left.f);
    } };



vector<node> search(Pos inicio,Pos desti){

    set<node> opennodes;
    vector<node> closednodes;
    node inici;
    node successor;
    inici.pos = inicio;
    inici.h = heuristic(inicio,desti);
    inici.g = getcost(inicio); 
    inici.f = inici.g + inici.h;
    opennodes.insert(inici);
    closednodes.push_back(inici);
    while(not opennodes.empty()){
        node current = *(opennodes.begin());
        opennodes.erase(opennodes.begin());
        if(current.pos == desti) cerr<<"encontrao";
        Dir direccio;
        for(int i = 0; i < 4;++i){
            if(i==0){
                    direccio = LEFT;

            }
            else if(i==1){
                    direccio = RIGHT;
            }
            else if(i==2){
                    direccio = TOP;
            }
            else {
                    direccio = BOTTOM;
            }

                successor.pos = current.pos + direccio;
                if(successor.pos == desti) return closednodes;
                if(pos_ok(successor.pos)){
                    successor.g = current.g + getcost(successor.pos);
                    successor.h = heuristic(successor.pos,desti);
                    successor.f = successor.g + successor.h;

                    node n1 = checkposition(successor.pos, opennodes); //I had to create two checkposition just to know if there's the node in the set or in the vector
                    node n2 = checkposition2(successor.pos, closednodes); 

                    if (n1.f != -1 and n1.f < successor.f);
                    else if (n2.f != -1 and n2.f < successor.f);
                    else opennodes.insert(successor);

                }
        }
          closednodes.push_back(current); 
        }

    return closednodes;
}
```

Comment: "and it is not working"  how is it not working?

Comment: It keeps in an infinite loop, like the opennode is never empty or something

Comment: 'like the opennode is never empty' well, what did your debugger tell you?  Try putting a break point in your insert method and make a very simple test case - then you can see if it's adding the items you expect.

Comment: in some cases I get a really strange path and in another ones the terminal keeps iterating in the loop without finishing

Answer (score 0):

So, first:

```
if(current.pos == desti) cerr<<"encontrao";
```

Shouldn't there be a break statement here? the cerr function doesn't break your loop, just throws and error message to your stdout.

And the for statement inside your while is always running up to 4, so direccio is always set to BOTTOM.
Other than that, I think the heuristic is fine, the problem is within the code structure, I'd suggest debugging it and posting here your results.

Comment: You re so right, I should have had a break statement here it was just an output message to debug. However my program stills fails. I don't see your point about direccio, I know that the last iteration is BOTTOM but each "child" (the next cell) is already set, isn't it?